# simplest steps to boot and install linux to a single usb hdd

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot

I cannot find any clear manual how to install debian bookworm in a new computer using usb hdd.

I tried to "restore iso image" using gnome-disks. However, after booting, trying to create partitions failed cause is the same bootable device "hdd is in use".
I have internet access. I can use jingo files? Just copy them to usb hdd and it will boot?
Note i have only "1" usb hdd and i would like to boot from this and install on this linux without using any other hdd device.

What are the simplest proper steps to boot from usb hdd with linux?
preferable using gnome-disks.

And yes i have searched internet.

So I have a new desktop PC machine, a passport usb hdd 5tb and I want to boot and install linux in it. How to do it?

Comment: You mention "disks' loosely without telling what physical disk you actually have and you're taking about. You ask several things in one question. This isn't a good question and I suggest you edit it, make it more concise and easier to follow.

Comment: I think usb hdd drives are just a single thing.... it is 5tb passport... what else doestn make sense? a new machine, a passport usb hdd... and want to boot and install linux in it... It can be simpler than that?

Comment: I am not going to discuss this. To me the question is unclear and unfocussed. Installing Linux is as straight forward as it can be, get an ISO > write it to USB flash drive > boot a USB flash drive with the Linux distro > select the drive to install to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `unetbootin` to make USB flash bootable with a Linux ISO image to another computer, and I connected the usb flash drive (and then USB HDD).

However, again setup told me "failed" to partition the disk. Therefore, I tried the advanced installation method which succeeded to partition the disk.

I don't know if this could have solved the initial problem with USB HDD.

Comment: If this solved the issue feel free to accept your own answer.